# Mysql Percona 5.6 Configuration File

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, my.cnf

I've just installed a Percona instance of Mysql on an Amazon server and can not find the `my.cnf` file anywhere. I found `auto.cnf` in `/var/lib/mysql` but there is nothing in that file like what I have seen for my standard mysql installs.

I'm using:

```
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.41-84.1, for Linux (x86_64) using  6.2
```

Previously I've used `5.6.14` and `5.6.35` I guess this version changed a bit?

I tried `mysqld --help --verbose | grep my.cnf | tr " " "\n"`, `find . -iname "my.cnf"`, `find / -iname "my.cnf"`, `locate my.cnf`, and `whereis my.cnf`. The `whereis` gave back a changed the shell, but had the same end result as all other commands which was no `my.cnf` found.

The `whereis` appended `my:` before my shell prompt e.g. `[root@ip-ip_address /]#`.

Mysql is running but from all SO threads I read there is no global variable I can select to find the conf file. Does anyone know how I can find where my configuration file lives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there is no global variable for the config file locations. `mysqld --help --verbose` is best to show which ones are used.

Take a look at the linux processlist to see how `mysqld` is executed by  init/service/systemd, that might specify a file.

Otherwise you might be running on a default config with no configuration file.

Comment: `mysqld --help --verbose` gives me back 5 `my.cnf`s but none of them actual exist when I use `ls` on the locations.

Comment: Which would indicate you have no configuration files. meaning you have a totally default configuration based on the internal defaults built into `mysqld`.

Comment: `ps aux | grep 'mysql' -i` gave me back `mysql .... /usr/sbin/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --plugin-dir=/usr/lib64/mysql/plugin --user=mysql --log-error=/var/lib/mysql/ip-LAN.err --pid-file=/var/lib/mysql/ip-LAN.pid` so that sounds like it is defining the settings dynamically. Can I do `touch /etc/my.cnf` and mysql will just use the file or do I need to set that up somewhere?

Comment: The `touch` worked for setting the settings but there is still no reference to it in the output of the `ps aux`. All the settings I changed are just added in with `--name=value`.

Answer (score 0):

Another place to look:

```
ls -ld /etc/*/my.cnf
```

It might be here:

```
/etc/mysql/percona-server.cnf
```

which is a softlink:

```
/etc/mysql/my.cnf -> /etc/alternatives/my.cnf -> /etc/mysql/percona-server.cnf
```